# Vue Router Dynamic Routing Issues and Warnings

Tags: vue-router, vuejs3

I don't understand what is wrong with Vue (3) Router.
I created this dynamic path:

```
    path: "/edit/:id",
    name: "Edit",
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/Edit.vue"),
  },
```

and when I pass `myapp.com/edit/123` to the address bar, the view is rendered correctly and I can use the `id` in the code, however I get this warn `Router warn]: No match found for location with path` **2 times**

Instead, if I do not pass any segment id, but I just try to open `myapp.com/edit` the view is not rendered and I still get the same warning **3 times**.

I dont get what is going wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Ok well, it was an easy fix. By just adding a question mark after the parameter, it becomes **optional** and the warning disappears `path: "/edit/:id?`